# Tufte-Latex sidenote breaks indentation in alltt

Tags: verbatim, tufte

I'm trying to the the [`alltt`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/alltt) environment in [`tufte-book`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tufte-latex). My problem is that `\sidenote` seems to break the indentation in `alltt`.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{alltt}

\begin{document}

\begin{alltt}
Some text that asdfasfd  \sidenote{Side note}
some more text
\end{alltt}

\end{document}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The verbatim environment does not either put the indentation space. I'm not sure that indentation has any sense inside a verbatim environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{alltt}


\begin{document}

\begin{alltt}
Some text that asdfasfd \sidenote{Side note}
\parindent0pt{}some more text
\end{alltt}

\end{document}
```

Note you need to be *very* careful with white space in such an environment. You have to use `{}` after `\parindent0pt` a space that would normally be OK would be typeset here.
Also `\noindent` (as used in the first draft) only works for one line, the next line would still be indented. (@egreg noted in chat)

---

One can patch `\sidenote` to behave properly in an `alltt` environment:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{alltt}

\makeatletter
\let\tufte@@sidenote\sidenote
\newcommand{\alltt@sidenote}[1]{\tufte@@sidenote{#1}\parindent=0pt}
\g@addto@macro\alltt{\let\sidenote\alltt@sidenote}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{alltt}
Some text that asdfasfd\sidenote{Side note} uuuu
some more text
and again text
\end{alltt}

\end{document}
```